# Variadic functions and composite types

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql, composite-types

I have a function like so:

```
update_stuff_variadic(
    VARIADIC _stuff_array stuff[]
)
```

I understand that this syntax requires _stuff_array to match the column structure of the stuff[] table.

Instead of implicitly matching every column of the stuff table, is it possible to set the required type of the elements in the array?

Pseudo:

```
update_stuff_variadic(
    VARIADIC _stuff_array array['comment'::BIGINT, 'created_by'::TEXT]
)
```

This way the array passed to the function doesn't have to accommodate for columns such as serial id fields, or auto-populated fields such as timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a registered composite type (row type).
You register a composite type implicitly whenever you create a table or view.
You register a composite type explicitly with [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html).

So you could:

```
CREATE TYPE my_partial_stuff AS (comment bigint, created_by text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_stuff_variadic(
    VARIADIC _stuff_array my_partial_stuff[]
) ...
```

And then call the function with:

```
SELECT update_stuff_variadic ('(8,foo)', '(9,bar)');
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you Erwin! :)

Answer (score 1):

I just looked for the same topic and found out that this is working well in my 'PostgreSQL 14.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit':

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(
    VARIADIC in_ttravalues anyarray DEFAULT null::anyarray
)
    RETURNS json
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
 -- do some stuff here
  return '{}'::json;
END
$BODY$
```

This allows to call:

```
SELECT * FROM myfunc( 'abc'::text, 123);
```